# Meaning of "Down" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Read the following sentence:

> It's a very steep road by the down.

Down has got a lot of [meanings](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/down_1)
, but what does it mean here? by the down?
I haven't read this type before so I've got no idea!

Comment: It is probably the meaning related to *hills* because the road is very steep. As in "Watership Down" and "The South Downs" (UK).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More context would be helpful, but it sounds like the word 'down' might be being used in its mainly British sense of an open chalk hill. Usually encountered as a plural, although the singular is possible. An area with a number of these is called 'downland'. A large part of southern England is made up of downland - the Berkshire Downs, the South Downs, and plenty of others, including the one in Kipling's poem "Merrow Down", which never fails to bring tears to my eyes.

> Of all the Tribe of Tegumai
>   Who cut that figure, none remain,
>   On Merrow Down the cuckoos cry
>   The silence and the sun remain.
>   But as the faithful years return
>   And hearts unwounded sing again,
>   Comes Taffy dancing through the fern
>   To lead the Surrey spring again.

[Full poem here](https://azdak.livejournal.com/104827.html)

[Downs (Geography)](http://downs%20noun%20[%20plural%20]%20UK%20%E2%80%8B%20%20/da%CA%8Anz/%20US%20%E2%80%8B%20%20/da%CA%8Anz/%20uk%20%E2%80%8B%20low%20hills%20covered%20in%20grass,%20especially%20used%20in%20the%20names%20of%20two%20such%20areas%20in%20southeast%20England:%20%20the%20North%20Downs%20the%20South%20Downs)

Comment: I appreciate your keen interest in making every single doubt cleared! thanks